# Instale el programa Composer, se instalo bien, pero no lo puedo ejecutar

Tags: composer

Instalé el programa **Composer**, se instaló bien, pero no lo puedo ejecutar.
Seguí las instrucciones que vienen aquí al píe de la letra:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

Al final de la instalación me sale el mensaje:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Ivan:word ivancaballerocano$ php composer-setup.php
>   All settings correct for using Composer
>   Downloading...
>
> Composer (version 1.8.6) successfully installed to: /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/countierEmergency/word/composer.phar
>   Use it: php composer.phar

Si pongo un `ls` me sale:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Ivan:word ivancaballerocano$ ls
>
> 1-download.txt     3-more.php      composer-setup.php
>
> 2-convert.php      README.txt      composer.phar

y ya cuando pongo el comando: `composer` me sale esto:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Ivan:word ivancaballerocano$ composer
>
> -bash: composer: command not found

Pues yo no sé casi nada de sistema operativo Unix..uso una MAC
Y no sé a que se debe que no parece estar "jalando" el comando, quizás sea por que no está bien direccionado la línea de configuración que jale los comandos.

Comment: pregunta tal vez obvia, ya cerraste la terminal y la volviste a abrir?

Comment: Ya hice eso de cerrar la terminal y volverla a abrir y no funciona aún.

Comment: Lo instalaste de forma local a un proyecto para ejecutarlo debeiras php composer.phar install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el instalador no pudo configurar la variable PATH del sistema, en ésta variable es donde se encuentran las rutas en las que el sistema operativo va a buscar los ejecutables o comandos si lo quieres ver de esa manera.

Entonces siguiendo ésta guía:

[Agregar Path a MAC](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

Hay que configurar la variable path para indicar la ruta donde se encuentra el ejecutable del composer.

Primero ejecutar:

> sudo nano /etc/paths

Esto abre el editor de texto para modificar las distintas rutas de la variable path, si pide contraseña colocarla.

Luego debes agregar la ruta como una nueva línea:

> /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/countierEmergency/word/composer.phar

Pulsas (para salir, cuando pregunte escribir Y para guardar el archivo)

> ctrl + x

Listo, ya deberías poder ejecutar el comando sin importar la ruta donde te encuentres.

Comment: gracias lo voy a intentar y les digo que paso

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que agregar el archivo composer.phar a tu PATH porque parece estar excluido de el.

```
mv /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/countierEmergency/word/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```